# Django: psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column "page_image" of "pages_page" relation does not exist

Tags: python, django, postgresql, mezzanine

Here is a brief backstory. I am using the Mezzanine CMS for Django. I created some models that inherited from the Mezzanine models. This caused an issue in my Postgres database, where one object was present in two tables. When I would try searching my site for a post, I would not get results from one table.

So, here is where I believe I messed up. I reverted my models to how they were before this issue. This meant that there was still a table in my database for those models, so my search function still wouldn't work. I wanted this relation gone, so I did something very stupid and deleted the entire database. This was fine for my local development, because I just recreated the database and migrated.

When I try deploying this project of mine with the newly created postgres database onto DigitalOcean, I get to this command:

`$ python manage.py createdb --nodata --noinput` which gives me the error:

```
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column "page_image" of "pages_page" relation does not exist
LINE 1: UPDATE "pages_page" SET "page_image" = '', "keywords_string"...
```

I looked up a few threads on this error, and tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57958722/django-python-loaddata-fails-with-django-db-utils-integrityerror) that did not work:

```py
python manage.py shell

>>> from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
>>> ContentType.objects.all().delete()
```

I have also tried the suggestion in the error `LINE 1: UPDATE "pages_page" SET "page_image" = '', "keywords_string"...`. The weird thing was, I saw the `page_image` column inside the `pages_page` table before running this command.

I do not know what code may be helpful in this case. I do not know how to troubleshoot this issue. How can I further troubleshoot this issue of mine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this issue out. It has something to do with the `EXTRA_MODEL_FIELDS` option in the `settings.py` file. I'm still not sure why that causes an issue, but here is my `EXTRA_MODEL_FIELDS` code:

```py
EXTRA_MODEL_FIELDS = (
     (
...,
     (
        "mezzanine.pages.models.Page.page_image",
        "ImageField",
        (_("Featured Image"),),
        {"blank": True, "upload_to": "uploads/blog"},   
     ),
...
 )
```

What I did that caused my issue to go away is as listed below:

- I deployed with the `createdb --nodata --noinput` command commented out.
- I continued the deployment process
- Once I got to deploying the website, I just ran migrations again
- The `page_image` column was automatically added

Now everything works fine! I don't know how much help this answer might be, but I can always go more into depth if someone wants to chat about their issues.